# Generics variable declaration in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, var

I have created a simple code in playground.

```
class CarBrand {

}

class Bmw: CarBrand {

}

class Mercedes: CarBrand {

}

class Car<T: CarBrand> {

}

class Employee {
    var car: Car<T: CarBrand>?// of cource this 
    doesn't work, but the idea is that there might be a car with any type
}

let employeeOne = Employee()
employeeOne.car = Car<BMw>()

let employeeTwo = Employee()
employeeTwo.car = Car<Mercedes>()
```

The simple question is: how to declare a variable with generics when the type is not known at compile time? It seems that Swift requires to have type defined and to be known but that makes generics useless in this scenario.

Comment: Does variable `car` cannot be a `CarBrand` type?

Comment: What's the need of the `Car` class if you could declare your property in `Employee` class as `var car: CarBrand?`?

Comment: "that makes generics useless". Exactly. You are using generics in a situation when normal type encapsulation would work much better and generics are actually a very bad decision.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird, class Car should holds a stored property like "brand" of type CarBrand rather than using this generic form. For example:

```
class Car {
  let brand: CarBrand

  init(brand: CarBrand) {
    self.brand = brand
  }
}

class Employee {
  var car: Car

  init(car: Car) {
    self.car = car
  }
}

let employeeOne = Employee(car: Car(brand: BMW()))
let employeeTwo = Employee(car: Car(brand: Mercedes()))
```

BTW, it might be better to define `CarBrand` as a *protocol*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are overthink about it, for such a case there is no need to declare *generic* variable, you could simply get rid of the `Car` class and declare the `car` property -in `Employee` class- to of type `CarBrand`:

```
class CarBrand { }

class Bmw: CarBrand { }

class Mercedes: CarBrand { }

class Employee {
    var car: CarBrand?
}

let employee = Employee()
employee.car = Mercedes()
```

Or, if there is a need to `Car` class, then I would suggest to follow [user5685969's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170830/generics-variable-declaration-in-swift).